# UI Is not updating when calling from background thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm, prism

I have a splash screen with a label this is implemented in MVVM pattern.I am updating label to notify user about the step. Initially it set to "Loading" then login screen comes up when user click login button and background thread is called to verify user from this background thread i update splash screen message by dispatcher this works fine but after we get the result of verify user. I updated splash screen status again to "Loading Modules..", but it is not updating. Below is my code.

```
 private void LoginCommandExecute()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            SplashController.Invoke(true, "Authenticating...");
            var result= AuthenticateUser();
            if (result)
            {
                SplashController.Invoke(true, "Loading Modules....");
                LoginNotification.Invoke(Infrastructure.Enums.Status.Success);
            }
        });
```

Below is used to show login windows and attache event to login view model.

```
 LoginControl.LoginViewModel lgVM = new LoginControl.LoginViewModel();
        lg = new LoginControl.Login();
        lg.DataContext = lgVM;
        lgVM.LoginNotification += (s) =>
          {
              if (s == Infrastructure.Enums.Status.Success)
              {

                      Task.Run(async () =>
                      {
                          closeLogin = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
                          await closeLogin.Task;
                          Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                          {
                              lg.Close();
                              lgVM.Dispose();
                              lg = null;
                              lgVM = null;
                          }, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);
                      });



                  Task.Run(() =>
                 {
                      Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                     {
                         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
                         lg.Hide();
                         BootStrapper bs = new BootStrapper();
                         bs.CloseSplash += () =>
                         {
                             if (closeLogin != null)
                                 closeLogin.TrySetResult(null);
                             sp.Close();
                             sp = null;
                         };
                         bs.Run();

                     });
                 });


              }
              else if(s==Infrastructure.Enums.Status.Canceled)
              {
                  if (!lg.IsClosing)
                      lg.Close();
                  if(sp!=null)
                      sp.Close();
              }
          };
        lgVM.SplashController += (sh, m) =>
          {
              if (sh)
              {                      
                  Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                  {
                      sp.Show();
                      spVM.Message = m;                          
                  },System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Send);
                  DoEvents();

              }
              else
                  sp.Hide();                      

          };
```

Comment: Why splash controller's dispatcher is not working?

Comment: Why do you sleep on the UI thread? I'd move `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);` before `Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>{`...

Comment: `Sleep`? `Invoke`? `DoEvents`? Take a step back and re-evaluate this entire code base.

Comment: Yes Haukinger, I put the system.threading.thread.sleep() to background thread and its works. Thanks